# phpstorm editor namespace highlight

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

This question is about a phpstorm editor feature.

In the image, right above the editor, there is some writing which shows the namespace\class (Illuminate\View\View) with brownish background (guess its the default color scheme).

Can someone be able to tell me what this feature is called in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is called "breadcrumbs"

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-with-breadcrumbs.html

Comment: Yes! that's it! Goodness thats annoying. Many thanks